# Excel text format, primary key can have both string or numeric format, how to vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with numeric identity number for each client:

[image: example].

The third number on this picture was made with adding a quote before the number: `'4346000273`. It makes excel read it as text number.

I use those numbers as the first argument for `Application.Vlookup` function in `vba` code.

I store the numbers as a `Client` class property, of type `String`:

```
Private identityNumber As String

Public Property Let setIdentityNumber(value As String)
    identityNumber = value
End Property

Public Property Get getIdentityNumber()
    getIdentityNumber = identityNumber
End Property

'inside another sub, which creates a list of clients:
clientCopy.setIdentityNumber = .Cells(i, column_identity).value

'how I use the numbers in VLookup
Function getInfo(clientIdentity As String, infoWorkbook As Workbook)
     resultValue = Application.VLookup(clientIdentity, _
                                 .Range(rangeString), 4, 0)
```

I wonder what is that a correct way to handle such situation. I worry there might happen a time when because of this format difference `Vlookup` wouldn't be able to find the numbers.

Comment: Try changing to `identityNumber = CStr(value)` or make a function to change to numbers and use `If IsNumeric(value) Then ....`

Comment: @danieltakeshi - if `identityNumber` is declared as a `string`, the VBEditor will try to parse it to string automatically.

Comment: You do have to ensure that your data types in VBA are the same as on the worksheet. Either format everything as text; or as number.  Formatting as number will remove leading zero's, if that might be an issue.  Or you could use a different method, that accounts for data type differences, to find the correct row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text number is not something, that exists in Excel. It is either `Text` or `Numeric`. The `VLookup` in VBA obviously does not like numeric values. To get around this "tricky" part, declare the argument as a range. Like this:

```
Public Function GetInfo(clientIdentification As Range) As Variant
    GetInfo = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(clientIdentification, _
        Range("A1:B3"), 2, False)
End Function
```

This is what you get:

[image]